# UITapGestureRecogniser add target not working

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uitapgesturerecognizer, addtarget

i have a objc function:

```
@objc private func segmentedControlViewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

I am trying to add this as a target for a gestureRecognizer but the code keeps crashing when i tap the segment control.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SegmentedControl.segmentedControlViewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
```

crashes due to: unrecognized selector sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action needs to point to a function in the target you specified.

Assuming the segmentedControlViewTapped is in your view or controller, change your code like this:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(segmentedControlViewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
```